# How often is performFetchWithCompletionHandler called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, network-programming, multitasking

Referring to iOS 7's Background Fetch feature.

I'm wondering how the following affect when `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` is called:

- User behavior

  - App use

    - **Frequency of app use** *(how does iOS determine which apps you use frequently?)*
    - **Timing of app use** *(time of day, time of week?)*
  - Phone use

    - **User unlocking phone** *(seems to trigger a fetch)*
    - **Timing of heavy phone use** *(does iOS know when you use your phone the most during the week?)*
- Network connectivity

  - **Data signal strength**
  - **Wi-Fi connection presence**
- App behavior

  - **Fetch interval**
  - **"Data" vs "No data" reporting**
  - **Use of content-available push**

Has anyone come up with anything definitive about **exactly how** these things affect the frequency and timing of `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:` calls?

Comment: We cannot be sure here of how Apple decides those things, as we are not Apple. The algorithms Apple uses are private and no one can know them, maybe guess them. And Stack Overflow is not a good site to answer questions that cannot be backed by facts.

Comment: @duci9y Thanks for the comment, but just because something is proprietary doesn't mean facts cannot be gathered about it. I can imagine lots of good answers to this question. For example, answers based on: statistics gathered by app developers about their apps' behavior in the wild; results of reverse-engineering iOS code; results of experiments done as part of app QA.

Answer (score 4):

I have been monitoring application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler calls in iOS 10 as part of app diagnostics. I noticed that when the app is in background (UIApplicationState == .background) and when I pass UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData to the completion handler - the function is called every 10 - 20 minutes.